# Android error "Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9961 (ple.myApp)" when using tesseract

Tags: android, android-studio, tesseract, tess-two

I get the above error when attempting to init a TessBaseAPI object to do some OCR.
I supply it with the path to the parent directory of "tessdata".
I'm new to android so not very sure what else to provide besides the snippet.
This error occurs whether debugging or not (the app just crashes)
Thank you

```
TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
baseApi.setDebug(true);
baseApi.init(_appDataPath, _language); //THIS IS WHERE IT CRASHES
```